# Move to next edittext in Pin screen

Tags: android, android-edittext

I know the question has been asked many a times, but none of their solutions worked for me. May be I am commiting some mistake. I want to move to next `EditText` onece I am done inputting in it. It is a pin screen with four edittexts.
I am expecting if we could do it through putting some code in layout xml only.

Here is part of my code  - 
`

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/outline"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <!-- android:nextFocusForward="@+id/num3" -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num3"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/outline"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <!-- android:nextFocusForward="@+id/num4" -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num4"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/outline"
        android:imeActionId="@+id/submit"
        android:imeActionLabel="Log In"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <!-- android:nextFocusForward="@+id/submit" -->
```

`

Comment: May be it is because I am using numerical keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the key pressed for 1st EditText and if it was "Enter" key,then move focus to next EditText.

```
et1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == 66) {
        et2.requestFocus();
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

Or you also can do it via Text Watcher, with it You can achieve this by using the Text Watcher class and then set the focus on the next EditText in the OnTextChanged() method of the TextWatcher.

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(et1.getText().toString().length()==size)     //size as per your requirement
    {
        et2.requestFocus();
    }
}
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

});
```

Comment: I was expecting some solution where I put some code in layout xml file. Not via code. Have any?

Comment: whatever you expect ,please specify in your question so that you may get clear answer

Comment: I tried it. Something weird is happening. when I click 'done' button from first edittext, it goes to third edittext, not in second one.

Comment: update the code with what you have implemented just now

Comment: @Darpan I think then problem is in your logic, check again your xml

Comment: Its working now, I could not understand why it was not working before. May be because of ImeActions I have set before, now removed.

Comment: @Darpan if its working fine, then please update code so that others can also use

Comment: what code you have posted here is enough to get it going.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {

    (0 until editTextArray.size)
        .forEach { i ->
            if (s === editTextArray[i].editableText) {

                if (s.isBlank()) {
                    return
                }
                if (s.length >= 2) {//if more than 1 char
                    val newTemp = s.toString().substring(s.length - 1, s.length)
                    if (newTemp != numTemp) {
                        editTextArray[i].setText(newTemp)
                    } else {
                        editTextArray[i].setText(s.toString().substring(0, s.length - 1))
                    }
                } else if (i != editTextArray.size - 1) { //1 char
                    editTextArray[i + 1].requestFocus()
                    editTextArray[i + 1].setSelection(editTextArray[i + 1].length())
                    return
                } else

                //will verify code the moment the last character is inserted and all digits have a number
                    verifyCode(testCodeValidity())


            }
        }
}
```

And add the onKeyListener to handle backspace:

```
editTextArray[index].setOnKeyListener { _, keyCode, event ->
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        //backspace
        if (index != 0) { //Don't implement for first digit
            editTextArray[index - 1].requestFocus()
            editTextArray[index - 1]
                 .setSelection(editTextArray[index - 1].length())
        }
    }
    false
}
```

Taken from this tutorial: https://medium.com/@Lev_Sharone/create-your-own-customized-pin-code-layout-in-3-simple-steps-e36d560689f8